# What can I do if my washing machine inlet hoses are not compatible with the plumbing?

Tags: installation, washing-machine

I purchased a fully automatic washing machine and little did I realize that it requires special plumbing to fit inlet hoses to water source. All I have got in my house are the taps to which it can be connected.I thought that I would be able to connect hose to tap when I operate washing machine and then remove it. But looks like this plan will not work.

I want to know if I can use inlet hose of semi-automatic washing machine (which doesn't require permanent fitting) with automatic washing machine?

The hose connector looks like:

[image: sample image]

Comment: What type of connections does it require?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about everyone else, but I'm still confused. Is the photo you posted the one your washer has or the one you want to use? Can you post whatever the other connector is and what your taps look like? This one appears to be prone to leakage, will that be a problem?

Comment: Please also post make and model number

Answer (score 1):

From the [installation instructions](http://image.haier.com/manual/ae/consumerproducts/washingmachine/toploading/201204/P020120406592863895667.pdf)<sup>1</sup> for Haier washing machines

> [image: Inlet Hose Connecting method]
>
> 1. Press the lower end of the lock lever and push down the slider. Take off the water inlet hose jointer from the water inlet hose component.
> 2. Loosen the screw till the water faucet can be accessed. Put the jointer of the water inlet hose on the faucet. (If the faucet is too large and the jointer can not be set on the water faucet,please loosen the four screws and take out the bushing in the jointer.
>    The front end of the faucet must be smooth, otherwise it may leak water
> 3. Fasten the four screws evenly.

That's it

<sup>1. Link is to a similar set of instructions; the diagrams are slightly different but the text is the same.</sup>

Comment: So, this is actually a spigot adapter, correct? Is the hose removable from the washing machine so you can use a standard MHT (Male Hose Thread) equipped spigot with a hose having FHT connectors on both ends?